# move_uploaded_file() not wordking in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i am using a custom form to upload image in wordpress,but move_uploaded_file is displaying a warning message .

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(user-images/Hydrangeas.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/kapoorha/public_html/kkn/wp-content/themes/KKN/edit-profile-step7.php on line 40
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpVfniNM' to 'user-images/Hydrangeas.jpg' in /home/kapoorha/public_html/kkn/wp-content/themes/KKN/edit-profile-step7.php on line 40

Answer (score 0):

Its not the problem with wordpress I think, actually the folder path is not getable!